# How to detect MouseLeave on a UIElement that is a Drag source in Silverlight when Dragging?

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, mouseleave, uielement

I have a `StackPanel` with `MouseLeave` events. I have run into an issue where `MouseLeave` events are not occurring for this `StackPanel` when elements are being dragged from this stack panel to other outside elements.

How can I have the `MouseLeave` event detected when Dragging?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See if the `DragLeave` event accomplishes what you want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.dragleave(VS.95).aspx

Comment: I don't think this will work. I am referring here to dragging and dropping UI objects as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189066(VS.95).aspx.